# How to fix "A RenderFlex overflowed by 1329 pixels on the right" on iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter

How do I resolve the exception "flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1329 pixels on the right"

```
getAgentSnippet(Snippet snippet) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          child: new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              ),
              new Container(
                child: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text('A')),
              ),
              new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  ),
                  new Text(model.name,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                  new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      snippet.text,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I get the exception seen below:

flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 327 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1753 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 487 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1381 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1308 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1347 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 53 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 293 pixels on the right.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 2141 pixels on the right.

[This is a overflow problem i'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofjGx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overflow exception is caused when the widget you are trying to display on the screen is too large to fit on the screen and thus an overflow occurs. From your picture it seems like you have text that you want to display but if the text is too long then it will overflow. You have two options:

- Make your text within your last container a scrollable text view to stop it from overflowing and instead allow the person to scroll to read it all. This can be achieved using a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Or

- Change your final Text widget at the bottom to a TextField with `maxLines` as `0` allowing the textfield to expand to fit the string length you pass to it.